# Using multiple audio.js playlist players on the same webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, playlist, audio-player

I am using the  [kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/test6.html](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/test6.html) audio.js playlist player (example 5).  That works great.  However, I would like to use two instances of it on the same page.

I have tried it, and the second instance player just displays a rotating circle (instead of the arrow for play).. and if you select any song from this second group, it plays, but shows up as playing on the first player.

You can see my attempt online here: [www.allanzavod.com/test-music3.htm](http://www.allanzavod.com/test-music3.htm)

Can you tell me if I am missing anything? Or is it **not** possible to have **multiple players** that also have the **playlist option**. (I know you can have multiple players with *no playlist* - as shown on example 2 of 'Custom markup/css': [kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/test2.html](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/test2.html)).

Originally, I was guessing that the problem was the fact that I had two divs with id="wrapper" (from the original code examples). But I think when I changed the name of the ids, it doesn't gel with the javascript.

Any suggestions? Any help will be appreciated!

(Sorry, I tried for an hour to get a jsfiddle setup, but just couldn't get the external references to work on it.  Hopefully you can see enough from the live example at:  [www.allanzavod.com/test-music3.htm](http://www.allanzavod.com/test-music3.htm))

Here is the code snippet:

```js
      $(function() { 
        // Setup the player to autoplay the next track
        var a = audiojs.createAll({
          trackEnded: function() {
            var next = $('ol li.playing').next();
            if (!next.length) next = $('ol li').first();
            next.addClass('playing').siblings().removeClass('playing');
            audio.load($('a', next).attr('data-src'));
            audio.play();
          }
        });
        
        // Load in the first track
        var audio = a[0];
            first = $('ol a').attr('data-src');
        $('ol li').first().addClass('playing');
        audio.load(first);

        // Load in a track on click
        $('ol li').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).addClass('playing').siblings().removeClass('playing');
          audio.load($('a', this).attr('data-src'));
          audio.play();
        });
        // Keyboard shortcuts
        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
          var unicode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
             // right arrow
          if (unicode == 39) {
            var next = $('li.playing').next();
            if (!next.length) next = $('ol li').first();
            next.click();
            // back arrow
          } else if (unicode == 37) {
            var prev = $('li.playing').prev();
            if (!prev.length) prev = $('ol li').last();
            prev.click();
            // spacebar
          } else if (unicode == 32) {
            audio.playPause();
          }
        })
      });
```

```css
* {padding: 0; margin: 0;} 


@font-face {
    font-family: 'BD Graduate';
    src: url('fonts/bdgrad.eot');  /* EOT file for IE */
    src: local('BD Graduate'), url('fonts/bdgrad.ttf') format('truetype');
}


HTML, BODY { 
  scrollbar-base-color: #90373A;
  scrollbar-shadow-color: #000000;
  scrollbar-highlight-color: #000000;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: #000000; 
}


html { 
    height: 100%; 
    margin-bottom: 1px; 
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url("images/zavod_dark_back3_tile.jpg"); 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: center top;
}
 
 
body {
    margin-width: 0px;
    margin-height: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
/*    background-image: url("images/zavod_dark_back5b.jpg"); */
    background-image: url("images/zavod_dark_back6b.jpg"); 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 30px; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #B4B4B4; /* sets the default type color */
}



a {
 color: #fff;
/* color: #90373A;  */
 text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover {
 color: #FBDDA0;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a.darklink {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

a.darklink:hover {
 color: #FBDDA0;
 text-decoration: none;
}





p {
 line-height: 140%;
 color: #B4B4B4;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: normal;
}


ul {
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 140%;
 font-weight: normal;
    list-style-type: disc;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 text-align: left;
 padding-left: 15px;
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-right: 10px; 
}


ol {
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 140%;
 font-weight: normal;
    list-style-type: disc;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 text-align: left;
 padding-left: 15px;
 margin-left: 15px;
}





#album1wrapper { color: #666; font-family: sans-serif; line-height: 1.4; }
#album1wrapper h1 { color: #444; font-size: 1.2em; padding: 0px 2px 12px; margin: 0px; }
#album1wrapper h1 em { font-style: normal; color: #999; }
#album1wrapper a { color: #888; text-decoration: none; }
#album1wrapper { width: 400px; margin: 0px auto 40px auto; }

#album1wrapper ol { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; list-style: decimal-leading-zero inside; color: #ccc; width: 460px; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; font-size: 0.9em; }
#album1wrapper ol li { position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 9px 2px 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; cursor: pointer; }
#album1wrapper ol li a { display: inline-block; text-indent: -3.3ex; padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px; }
#album1wrapper li.playing { color: #aaa; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); }
#album1wrapper li.playing a { color: #fff; }
#album1wrapper li.playing:before { content: '\266C'; width: 14px; height: 14px; padding: 3px; line-height: 14px; margin: 0px; position: absolute; left: -24px; top: 9px; color: #fff; font-size: 13px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4); }

@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
#album1wrapper { position: relative; left: -3%; }
}

#album2wrapper { color: #666; font-family: sans-serif; line-height: 1.4; }
#album2wrapper h1 { color: #444; font-size: 1.2em; padding: 0px 2px 12px; margin: 0px; }
#album2wrapper h1 em { font-style: normal; color: #999; }
#album2wrapper a { color: #888; text-decoration: none; }
#album2wrapper { width: 400px; margin: 0px auto 40px auto; }

#album2wrapper ol { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; list-style: decimal-leading-zero inside; color: #ccc; width: 460px; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; font-size: 0.9em; }
#album2wrapper ol li { position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 9px 2px 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; cursor: pointer; }
#album2wrapper ol li a { display: inline-block; text-indent: -3.3ex; padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px; }
#album2wrapper li.playing { color: #aaa; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); }
#album2wrapper li.playing a { color: #fff; }
#album2wrapper li.playing:before { content: '\266C'; width: 14px; height: 14px; padding: 3px; line-height: 14px; margin: 0px; position: absolute; left: -24px; top: 9px; color: #fff; font-size: 13px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4); }

@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
#album2wrapper { position: relative; left: -3%; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">



<head>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.allanzavod.com/audiojs/audio.js"></script>
 
 

</head>

<body  OnLoad="window.focus();">

 <br clear="all" /><br />
 <br clear="all" /><br />

 <div id="album1wrapper">
      <h1>wait what - notorious xx <em>(2009)</em></h1>
      <audio preload></audio>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/01-dead-wrong-intro.mp3">dead wrong intro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/02-juicy-r.mp3">juicy-r</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/03-its-all-about-the-crystalizabeths.mp3">it's all about the crystalizabeths</a></li>
      </ol>
    </div>

 
 
 <br clear="all" /><br />
 <br clear="all" /><br />

 
 <div id="album2wrapper">
      <h1>wait what - notorious xx <em>(2009)</em></h1>
      <audio preload></audio>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/09-infinite-victory.mp3">infinite victory</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/10-the-curious-incident-of-big-poppa-in-the-nighttime.mp3">the curious incident of big poppa in the nighttime</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/11-mo-stars-mo-problems.mp3">mo stars mo problems</a></li>
      </ol>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include text of `html`, `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: I've edited my post to include the 'code snippet' that can be run to see the problem.

Comment: You are attaching events to only first `<audio>` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching events to only first `<audio>` element. Each portion of `javascript` requires filtering tasks for each `<audio>` element and `audio` variable using `.closest()`, `$.each()`, `.each()`, `.index()`, `.find()`

```js
$(function() {

  var a = audiojs.createAll({
    trackEnded: function() {
      var el = $(this.element);
      var next = el.closest(".audiojs").next('ol').find("li.playing").next();
      if (!next.length) next = el.closest(".audiojs").next("ol").find("li").first();
      next.parent().find(".playing").removeClass("playing");
      next.addClass('playing');
      el.attr("src", $('> a', next).attr('data-src'));
      el.on("canplay", function() {
        this.play()
      })
    }
  });
  // Load in the first track
  var audio = a;
  $.each(audio, function(index, el) {
    var first = $(el.wrapper).next("ol").find("li:first")
      .addClass("playing").find("a").attr("data-src");
    el.load(first);
  });
  // Load in a track on click
  $('ol li').click(function(e) {
    var index = $(this).closest("ol").index("ol");
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('playing').siblings()
      .removeClass('playing');
      var el = $('> a', this);
      el.attr("src", el.attr('data-src'));
      el.on("canplay", function() {
        this.play()
      })
  });
  // Keyboard shortcuts
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var unicode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
    var elems = $('li.playing');
    elems.each(function(i, el) {
      var curr = $(el);
      // right arrow
      if (unicode == 39) {
        var next = curr.next();
        if (!next.length) {
          next = curr.closest("ol").find("li").first();
          next.click();
        }
        // back arrow
      } else if (unicode == 37) {
        var prev = curr.prev();
        if (!prev.length) {
          prev = curr.closest("ol").find("li").last();
          prev.click();
        }
        // spacebar
      } else if (unicode == 32) {
        $.each(audio, function(i, media) {
          media.playPause();
        })
      }
    })
  })
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BD Graduate';
  src: url('fonts/bdgrad.eot');
  /* EOT file for IE */
  src: local('BD Graduate'), url('fonts/bdgrad.ttf') format('truetype');
}
HTML,
BODY {
  scrollbar-base-color: #90373A;
  scrollbar-shadow-color: #000000;
  scrollbar-highlight-color: #000000;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: #000000;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url("images/zavod_dark_back3_tile.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: center top;
}
body {
  margin-width: 0px;
  margin-height: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  /*    background-image: url("images/zavod_dark_back5b.jpg"); */
  background-image: url("images/zavod_dark_back6b.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #B4B4B4;
  /* sets the default type color */
}
a {
  color: #fff;
  /* color: #90373A;  */
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
  color: #FBDDA0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.darklink {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a.darklink:hover {
  color: #FBDDA0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
p {
  line-height: 140%;
  color: #B4B4B4;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
ul {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 140%;
  font-weight: normal;
  list-style-type: disc;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
ol {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 140%;
  font-weight: normal;
  list-style-type: disc;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
#album1wrapper {
  color: #666;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
#album1wrapper h1 {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 0px 2px 12px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#album1wrapper h1 em {
  font-style: normal;
  color: #999;
}
#album1wrapper a {
  color: #888;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#album1wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0px auto 40px auto;
}
#album1wrapper ol {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: decimal-leading-zero inside;
  color: #ccc;
  width: 460px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
#album1wrapper ol li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 9px 2px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#album1wrapper ol li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -3.3ex;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}
#album1wrapper li.playing {
  color: #aaa;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
#album1wrapper li.playing a {
  color: #fff;
}
#album1wrapper li.playing:before {
  content: '\266C';
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  padding: 3px;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -24px;
  top: 9px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  #album1wrapper {
    position: relative;
    left: -3%;
  }
}
#album2wrapper {
  color: #666;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
#album2wrapper h1 {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 0px 2px 12px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#album2wrapper h1 em {
  font-style: normal;
  color: #999;
}
#album2wrapper a {
  color: #888;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#album2wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0px auto 40px auto;
}
#album2wrapper ol {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: decimal-leading-zero inside;
  color: #ccc;
  width: 460px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
#album2wrapper ol li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 9px 2px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#album2wrapper ol li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -3.3ex;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}
#album2wrapper li.playing {
  color: #aaa;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
#album2wrapper li.playing a {
  color: #fff;
}
#album2wrapper li.playing:before {
  content: '\266C';
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  padding: 3px;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -24px;
  top: 9px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  #album2wrapper {
    position: relative;
    left: -3%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.allanzavod.com/audiojs/audio.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="window.focus();">
  <br clear="all" />
  <br />
  <br clear="all" />
  <br />

  <div id="album1wrapper">
    <h1>Album 1</h1>
    <audio preload></audio>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/01-dead-wrong-intro.mp3">dead wrong intro</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/02-juicy-r.mp3">juicy-r</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/03-its-all-about-the-crystalizabeths.mp3">it's all about the crystalizabeths</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>

  <br clear="all" />
  <br />
  <br clear="all" />
  <br />

  <div id="album2wrapper">
    <h1>Album 2</h1>
    <audio preload></audio>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/09-infinite-victory.mp3">infinite victory</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/10-the-curious-incident-of-big-poppa-in-the-nighttime.mp3">the curious incident of big poppa in the nighttime</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/11-mo-stars-mo-problems.mp3">mo stars mo problems</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That works perfect!  Thank you so much for your help!  Is there an easy way to get the 2nd player to default to play the 1st song of it's group (& have the music note icon next to it's 1st song) when the page first loads?  Right now, the 2nd player plays the 1st song of the 1st player.  It works correctly if you click on any song in the 2nd players group.  But what I want is when the page first loads, if you just hit play on the 2nd player, it will get the 1st song from that album.. not from the 1st album.  Right now player 2 will start playing "dead wrong intro" instead of "infinite victory"

Comment: Just FYI, I am planning on adding about 15 players (for 15 different albums) on the same page, and it would get confusing if each player would all start off playing the same song (if no individual song was clicked for that player).  That's why I need the 1st song of each album (player) to be the default for it's player (if no song is actually selected first).

Comment: @SunnyOz See updated post. Included `var first = $(el.wrapper).next("ol").find("li:first")
                .addClass("playing").find("a").attr("data-src");
    el.load(first);` at `$.each(audio, function(){})` loop, removed previous declaration of `first`

Comment: Absolutely perfect!!  I am so grateful for your help.  Thanks for making the extra effort.  I wish I could up-vote you more than once!  Cheers.

Comment: I'm trying to use the above script, which works good until a track ends and the next one should get played. Then I'm getting this error: *Uncaught TypeError: el.play is not a function* can anyone help me getting this to work?

Comment: @guest271314 - thank you for getting into this...here's a fiddle of the code....https://jsfiddle.net/j7rLue3q/ ...the problem is in line 20, when the "el.play();" should get fired.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error that you are describing, though protocol of `document` and requested resource should match.

Comment: So on your side the player-instances both do play the next song of their playlist when the current one is finished? That's the problem i need to solve. When i start the player of Album 1, the first song starts playing. When it's finished the 2nd song should automatically get played. The error message varies in the inspector in fiddle, but it behaves the same by not starting the next song. Same for the player of Album2

Comment: @guest271314 thanks a lot for getting into this again...but in your fiddle-link there's no script inside? so right now it's not working at all.

Comment: @EMEm https://jsfiddle.net/j7rLue3q/3/ , https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @guest271314 - thank you for pointing me on this!If i'm getting you correct, a stacksnippet already exists in this post above. In it the same error happens like I described before. Do you want me to create a new post with this same example?

Comment: @guest271314 - ah, saw your new fiddle later than my first response...and yeah, that's what I'm looking for I think. In my first test it seems to be working...thanks a lot for your help on this, I really appreciate this! Only thing i recognized is, that the "next" song plays when the current one ends, but the "play"-button remains when the next-song starts...so you have to click twice for this to stop manually. But I think I can sort that out by myself! A big thank you again!

Comment: @guest271314 - I tried to use this script on my project, but now I realized that the "Load a track on click"-function doesn't work anymore...strangeise I don't get any error message...hm...trying to sort that out now...