# Multiple audio players on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I'm attempting to create two audio players on the same page.  I've seen a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283018/using-multiple-audio-js-playlist-players-on-the-same-webpage), which suggested, "filtering tasks for each audio element and audio value," but my player is so different than the one in that question that I'm not sure how to apply it to mine. 
Whenever I try to play the first player, the second starts instead and breaks if I start clicking around. The scripts for the two players are in different files, I've already changed the IDs so there aren't duplicates, and I also tried changing the variable and function names thinking that maybe they were having some impact. Nothing has worked.

I'm using the same code for each player, but with a different prefix on each ID:

```
/* global $ */

var audio;

//Hide Pause
$('#pause').hide();

initAudio($('#playlist').find('li:first-child'));

$('#playlist').on('click', function(event) {
    initAudio($(event.target));
});

// Initiate play sequence
function initAudio(element){
    var recording = element.attr('data-id');
    var title = element.text();
    var artist = element.attr('data-artist');

    //Create audio object
    audio = new Audio('public/audio_files/'+ recording);

    //Insert audio info
    $('.artist').text(artist);
    $('.title').text(title);

    $('#playlist li').removeClass('active');
    element.addClass('active');

    // Set timer to 0
    $('#duration').html('0:00');

    // Maintain volume on song change
    audio.volume = $('#volume').val() / 100;
}

//Play button
$('#play').click(function() {
    audio.play();
    showPause();
    showDuration();
});

//Pause button
$('#pause').click(function() {
    audio.pause();
    showPlay();
});

//Next button
$('#next').click(function() {
    audio.pause();
    var next = $('#playlist li.active').next();
    if(next.length == 0){
        next = $('#playlist li:first-child');
    }
    showPause();
    initAudio(next);
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
});

//Prev button
$('#prev').click(function() {
    audio.pause();
    var prev = $('#playlist li.active').prev();
    if(prev.length == 0){
        prev = $('#playlist li:last-child');
    }
    showPause();
    initAudio(prev);
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
});

//Playlist song click
$('#playlist li').click(function() {
    audio.pause();
    initAudio($(this));
    showPause();
    audio.play();
    showDuration();
});

//Volume control
$('#volume').change(function() {
    audio.volume = parseFloat(this.value / 100);
});

// Show play button, hide pause
function showPlay() {
  $('#play').show();
    $('#pause').hide();
}

// Show pause button, hide play
function showPause() {
  $('#play').hide();
  $('#pause').show();
}

// Automatically play next song
function autoPlayNext() {
    if(audio.currentTime == audio.duration) {
        var next = $('#playlist li.active').next();
        if(next.length == 0){
            next = $('#playlist li:first-child');
        }
        showPause();
        initAudio(next);
        audio.play();
        showDuration();
    }
} 

// Time/Duration
function showDuration() {
    $(audio).bind('timeupdate', function() {
        //Get hours and minutes
        var s = parseInt(audio.currentTime % 60, 10);
        var m = parseInt(audio.currentTime / 60, 10) % 60;
        if(s < 10) {
            s = '0' + s;
        }
        $('#duration').html(m + ':'+ s);
        var value = 0;
        if(audio.currentTime > 0){
            value = Math.floor((100 / audio.duration) * audio.currentTime);
        }
        $('#progress').css('width', value + '%');

        autoPlayNext();
    });
}

// Skip time via progress bar click
$('#progress-bar').bind('click', function (e) {
    var $div = $(e.target);

    var offset = $div.offset();
    var x = e.clientX - offset.left;

    audio.currentTime = ((x / 2.3)/(100 / audio.duration)); /* length of progress-bar is 230px hence (x/2.3) */
});
```

Any insight?

Comment: `initAudio` is reassigning the `audio` variable. You should use a Constructor if you truly want separate instances.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that makes sense. I am, however, confused as to how to go about assigning property values, data-id, data-artist, etc., when they're changing with each audio_file within each instance.
Would you be so kind as to explain how that would work?